# EF - InvalidOperationException Error when Saving after Adding Item to Virtual ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Model :

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Followers { get; set; }
 }
```

Method :

```
public void Follow(int id)
    {
        if (id != AppUser.UserProfile.Id)
        {
            UserProfile profile = db.UserProfile.Find(id);
            if (profile != null)
            {
                if (profile.Followers.Contains(AppUser.UserProfile))
                {
                     profile.Followers.Remove(AppUser.UserProfile);
                }
                else
                {
                    profile.Followers.Add(AppUser.UserProfile);
                }
                db.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified; //error here
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
```

When a user follows another user, the user gets added to the Followers ICollection. If the user is already following, then the user gets removed from Followers.

When I am attempting to update the database, I get this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.'

How can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `AppUser.UserProfile` is not in `db` context.
You can attach `AppUser.UserProfile` to the context you need or you can read a `UserProfile` from `db` context ( `Find(AppUser.UserProfile.Id`) ).
Just in case, don't clone `AppUser.UserProfile` without attaching it to context otherwise EF will add e new `UserProfile`.

Comment: "Just in case, don't clone AppUser.UserProfile without attaching it to context otherwise EF will add e new UserProfile. " What do you mean by this? @bubi

Comment: First time I saw this error I cloned (copy properties) the entity. SaveChanges then works but the effect is that the cloned entity is added to database.